# Relação entre lista de requisitos e casos de uso

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software, casos-de-uso

Ao começar a desenvolver um sistema, e inclusive ao longo do processo de desenvolvimento, é comum mantermos uma lista com os requisitos funcionais do mesmo. No meu entendimento sempre começamos montando essa lista e depois a partir dela escrevemos casos de uso para descrever em detalhes a interação entre o usuário e o sistema. É importante ressaltar que não estou falando de *diagrama* de casos de uso, mas sim dos casos de uso em si.

Acontece que nos ultimos tempos estou lendo um livro sobre análise e projeto em orientação a objetos e o livro sugere que além disso seja feito também o contrário, ou seja, ao escrever um caso de uso verificar se é preciso adicionar mais algum requisito a lista.

Não entendi isso, por que isso seria feito? Ao meu ver, listar os requisitos funcionais é justamente pra encontrar os casos de uso e saber o que é necessário descrever do sistema. Qual o fundamento de fazer o processo reverso e começar pelo caso de uso? No meu entendimento começando pelo caso de uso não existe nenhuma utilidade em adicionar nada na lista de requisitos funcionais.

Comment: qual a referência bibliográfica?

Comment: É o livro "Use a cabeça! Análise e Projeto Orientados a Objetos".

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando se adota um processo formal de Engenharia de Software, é importante que os diversos artefatos (documentos, modelos) estejam **consistentes** entre si. Pois se esses artefatos existem, é para serem consultados, e se um ou mais deles estão defasados, eles perdem a utilidade como material de referência - se tornam "trabalho inútil", que alguém desperdiçou tempo escrevendo para no final ser jogado fora.

Por essa razão, se ao longo do projeto você determina que uma funcionalidade nova é interessante, mas você já está bem avançado no desenvolvimento, é tentador simplesmente implementá-la e deixar ela de fora de tudo o que foi feito lá atrás (especificação de requisitos, modelos de análise, etc). Ao fazer isso, não só você contribui para a inconsistência entre o que é descrito que o sistema faz e o que o sistema faz de fato, como também incorre no risco adicional de se estourar o prazo e o orçamento (pois os mesmos foram estimados com base no projeto, e essa estimativa precisa ser continuamente revista à medida que os requisitos mudam). Por fim, você pode estar sendo vítima de *scope creep* - caso em que se começa a agregar funcionalidades novas ao sistemas simplesmente "porque pode" ou "porque o cliente quer", sem que isso se justifique dada a missão do sistema.

Ok, mas isso significa então que cada documentozinho precisa ser atualizado sempre que algo mudar? Aí depende do seguinte: essa "lista de requisitos" é um documento **permanente** ou não? É algo que faz parte da linha de base do projeto, ou algo que você escreveu como *brainstorm*, para ser usada e jogada fora depois? Alguns processos mais burocráticos exigem (ou tentam exigir) que tudo seja meticulosamente documentado, que nada saia dos planos, e que a cada mudança todos os artefatos sejam atualizados para refleti-la, mesmo quando isso é inviável na prática e/ou esses documentos e modelos raramente ou nunca sejam consultados por ninguém. Outros já prevêem - ainda que de forma organizada - a obsolescência de certos artefatos, e preferem arquivá-los a mantê-los atualizados.

Cabe então a você determinar, caso a caso, o que faz sentido manter e o que faz sentido arquivar. Essa "lista de requisitos" ajuda a quem? Ao cliente? Só aos desenvolvedores? A outros atores no processo de desenvolvimento? E a relação de casos de uso, ajuda a quem? Cada empresa, cada equipe, pode fazer isso de forma diferente, com prós e contras que são alvo de muita discussão acalorada. O mais importante, seja numa equipe organizada ou mesmo numa desorganizada (i.e. que se propõe a seguir um processo, mas que sempre acaba se desviando dele) é diferenciar quais documentos estão consistentes com o sistema tal como está (ou tal como ficará) e quais estão obsoletos, para que outros não percam tempo e/ou tenham suas expectativas frustradas por estar consultando algo que não condiz com a realidade do projeto.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta @mgibsonbr, estou com um projeto multidisciplinar da faculdade e pensei sobre essa questão, a única coisa que altero na análise é o protótipo geralmente, não estou chegando a mudar os casos de uso, mas é um ótimo aprendizado essa relação e o que você respondeu aqui nessa pergunta. +1